# how to recover a libraoffice ods file

Tags: 20.04, data-recovery

so i have this file , i made sure i save it , after rebooting ,it is gone , i searched for it i found this

```
$sudo find / -name "*.ods#" 2>/dev/null 
/home/an/Documents/.~lock.stud_sch.ods#

$cat /home/an/Documents/.~lock.stud_sch.ods#
,an,usr1,25.03.2021 14:44,file:///home/an/.config/libreoffice/4;a
```

i dont know if it is related , but i made new file with same file name so , is there any way to recover this, i tried to find soulotion online , majority of answer is "if you open libraoffice you will find files that you can restore in start up pop up window " and i tried also to go to tools>paths i checked the documents path and backups path ,found nothing

Comment: If you made a new file with the same name the other file is gone for good.

Answer (score 1):

This lock file doesn't contain any content of the original document, it can't help you to restore lost file.
LO stores autorecovery data in /tmp, if your configuration remains default. After rebooting this directory was cleaned. You seem to have lost your document, unfortunately. That's true, that if LO haven't proposed file restore, it's probably lost.
Related discussions on askLO:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/46776/where-is-the-autorecovery-information-saved/
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/28969/libreoffice-crashed-on-save-any-chance-of-recovery/